# QUnit Testing: reveal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

Hello I'm very new to JavaScript Unit Testing, and I'm in the process of attempting to see if it would be possible to test some existing JavaScript.

I've got my test runner up, but I'm receiving this error in regards to function.

Test Runner the markup there is just to test something for the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>QUnit Main Test Suite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../qunit.css">     
    <script src="../sinon-1.17.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../qunit.js"></script>
    <script src="PreferenceControl.js"></script>  
    <script src="tests.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id='MainContentDiv'>
        <div id='PreferenceType'>PreferenceFrequency</div>
        <div id='PreferenceId'>1</div>
        <table id='RadioButtonList'>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span id='1'>
                        <input id='RadioButtonList_0' type='radio' name='RadioButtonList' value='1'>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span id='2'>
                        <input id='RadioButtonList_1' type='radio' name='RadioButtonList' value='2' checked='checked'>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span id='3'>
                        <input id='RadioButtonList_2' type='radio' name='RadioButtonList' value='3'>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span id='4'>
                        <input id='RadioButtonList_3' type='radio' name='RadioButtonList' value='4'>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" id="SaveButton" />
      </div>
      <div id="CheckBoxList"></div>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">test markup</div>
</body>
```

Below is the section it's breaking on:

```
this.loaderContainer = $('#AjaxLoader', this.mainContentDiv);

if (this.loaderContainer.length == 0) {
    this.loaderContainer = $("<div id=\"AjaxLoader\" class=\"full-width columns alpha omega\">" +
                                "<span class=\"loader\"><img src=\"/Common/CSS/Core/Images/Throbbers/Ajax-Loader.gif\" style=\"display: none\" ></span>" +
                            "</div>");

    this.loaderContainer.appendTo(this.mainContentDiv);
}

this.loaderContainer.reveal({
    animation: 'throbber'
});
```

These are the results of my break:

[image]

I'm not sure how to rectify this, or if it's possible the way I've done it? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think `reveal` should be a function on a jQuery object? Your question is incomplete without that information. Is there some plugin you are trying to use? Did you forget to include http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin?

Comment: That's the point, it's not. I was missing a reference to the plugin. I don't particularly think this question is incomplete, as someone who knows about this plugin would realize I'm trying to call it without referencing it. You say it's incomplete without this information, but that IS the information that I needed to fix it.

Comment: Forgetting to link to a file is one of the reasons a question should be closed/deleted. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322738/should-questions-resolved-by-missing-javascript-files-be-closed

Comment: Ok then lets delete it. I wasn't aware that was a rule here Sorry but you come across as a bit rude with your response to it.

Comment: I know, I can sound rude sometimes, I'll work on that. At least I provided you factual information to help you improve future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a missed reference to another library that deals with the .reveal method.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have a `reveal()` method. I'm not sure what you're trying to do on that line of code, but perhaps you're looking for the `show()` method with an [`easing` option specified](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-options)?

The error you're seeing from QUnit is that the `reveal()` function does not exist (because it is not part of jQuery). If you are using a plugin that provides a `reveal()` function for you then you need to include that JS file in your test harness (the HTML document).

Comment: It's from another plugin. The line of code is revealing that element with an animation, hence, .reveal with an animation param set. This question is like over a month old now, perhaps I should have just answered it myself.

Comment: @ICTech Yes, it would be polite to either delete the post or answer it yourself, otherwise, others are wasting their time trying to help you.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes I should have, I completely forgot about it to be honest and wasn't expecting someone to dig out a month old question.